# Wrap the default DataTemplate using a 2nd DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, stack-overflow, datatemplate

In my specific case I need to present a collection of objects and would like to make all instances of certain types right-aligned but not otherwise modify their display. I attempted to do that using a data template that included a content presenter like so:

```
<me:MyDisplay>
    <me:MyDisplay.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type foo:bar}">
            <Border HorizontalAligment="Stretch">
               <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
     </me:MyDisplay.Resources>
</me:MyDisplay>
```

But this throws a `StackOverflowException`.

Here is the xaml from a simple test app that attempts what I am trying to do:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<Window.Resources>

    <sys:Int32 x:Key="test">42</sys:Int32>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
        <Border Background="Red"
                Padding="10">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       Foreground="Green" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <!-- uses default template -->
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource test}" />

    <Border>
        <Border.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
                <!-- Wrap default template in a blue border -->
                <Border Background="Blue"
                        Padding="10">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Border.Resources>

        <!-- ...but it doesn't work. -->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource test}" />
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a good way to pull this off?

Comment: I'm not sure I get this. Why do you need 2 DataTemplates at all? Just ditch one of them.

Comment: I see my test code doesn't do a good job of capturing my use case. I have a mixed collection of objects; I need to apply special formatting to instances of certain types (e.g. wrap them in a border, align this way or that, and so forth) but other than this formatting I don't want to dictate how the data is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You defined your `DataTemplate` as an implicit data template (you didn't specify a key for it) which means it will automatically be used by any contained controls, including the `ContentPresenter` inside it.

This causes the `ContentPresenter` to reference the `DataTemplate` which then references the `ContentPresenter` in an endless loop, which causes the `StackOverflowException`.

To fix this, you can simply give your `DataTemplate` a key and use it:

```
<Border>
    <Border.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}" x:Key="myDataTemplate">
            <!-- Wrap default template in a blue border -->
            <Border Background="Blue"
                    Padding="10">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Border.Resources>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource test}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}" />
</Border>
```

Comment: This does eliminate the error in my test code but I'm not sure I see how to apply it to my use case.